# Why is this PHP-PDO script failing to connect to MySQL server on localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ubuntu 14.04, MySQL 5.5, PHP5, PHP5-mysql - nothing outside Ubuntu 14.04 distro versions - Here's the error and code:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '(localhost)' (11)

```
<?php
$db_host='localhost';
$db_name='my_guitar_shop2';
$db_user='included';
$db_pass='included';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=($db_host);dbname=($db_name)", $db_user, $db_pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM products');

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    print r($results);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

A MySQLi version of the code (not shown) - returns data from the MySQL database. This PHP-PDO version of the code returns the error. I have substituted the loop address, and my PC's IP, and various combinations. So far only the MySQLi works. I want to be able to use PDO. Is there an error in the script? What could be wrong?

This app limited my comments to 180 characters, and I don't know how to respond with more code, so I'm editing the question. Sorry for my ignorance.

This is what I ended up with that worked:

```
<?php

define("SQLHOST", "localhost");
define("SQLUSER", "included");
define("SQLPASS", "included");
define("SQLSGBD", "my_guitar_shop2");

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . SQLHOST . ';dbname=' . SQLSGBD . ';charset=UTF8', SQLUSER, SQLPASS);

if ($pdo) {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT productName, description, listPrice FROM products");
if ($stmt) {
  if($stmt->execute()); {
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      echo "Item: " . $row['productName']."<br/>";
      echo "Description: " . $row['description']."<br/>";
      echo "List Price: " . $row['listPrice']."<br/>";
      echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I was most interested in getting PDO to work, so I stripped out the error checking. Thanks again for the responses.

Comment: You need to write `{$db_host}` in the PDO declaration, not `($db_host)` (and the same with db_name).

Comment: Why even bother using variables in this case? You aren't going to use them anywhere else. Just go with `new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_guitar_shop2;charset=utf8', 'included', 'included')`

Answer (score 4):

Look closely at the error message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '(localhost)'
```

You will see that the hostname is in parentheses. Looking at the code the reason is obvious

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=($db_host);dbname=($db_name)", $db_user, $db_pass);
```

There are parentheses, too. Remove them!

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use this?:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=($db_host);dbname=($db_name)", $db_user, $db_pass);
```

try using this instead! This should work:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=($db_host);dbname=" . $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor doesn't look quite right, try this instead:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$db_host;

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

If it still fails, then copy to your question a whole stacktrace with exception text.

Answer (score -3):

here is the proper way to do it with PDO you might want to consider.

**Comments:**

1/ replace localhost by 127.0.0.1. This is much faster in any circumstances.

2/ avoid using while to iterate across arrays. foreach is faster and made for.

3/ In your example you also use * in your SQL, this is considered bad practice.

```
$exitOnError = true;

define("SQLHOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("SQLUSER", "login");
define("SQLPASS", "password");
define("SQLSGBD", "my_guitar_shop2");

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . SQLHOST . ';dbname=' . SQLSGBD . ';charset=UTF8', SQLUSER, SQLPASS);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql1 = 'SELECT designation, price, description FROM products';
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);

try {
    $stmt1->execute();
    $objs1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($exitOnError === true) {
        var_dump("error query 1:" . __LINE__ . "-------" . __FUNCTION__ . "-------" . $e->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
}
if (count($objs1) !== 0) {
    $pricesList=array();
    foreach ($objs1 as $key1 => $result1) {
        $pricesList[] = $result1['price'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `localhost` will use a local socket connection if available which is vastly more preferable than connecting over TCP to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Having a dedicated TCP is always preferable than a loopback localhost that will anyway generates TCP overhead.

Comment: To elaborate more, it depends on the software and how it is handled. for mysql, it s faster, no doubt about that if on the same host. SQL or postgres, not sure...

Comment: I got PDO to dump the database to print, and that was my main concern. I'm near day one with PHP, and year 20 with db - so learning PHP-MySQL should be a breeze from here out. Thanks so much for the help.